# Simulate a cron job from particular domain

Tags: php, cron, vtiger, vtigercrm

I am developing a integrated web application with vTiger. And in certain cases I want to execute a cron job.

The file is on server xyz.com. And there are multiple subdomains on my server.

But when the cron will be executed can I set the request origin from subdomain1.xyz.com or subdomain2.xyz.com etc

Can anyone please help me. Thanks in advnance

Answer (score 1):

As far i can tell, you do not have access to crontab but still have to perform automated tasks?

The easiest solution would be to perform check on every user request, and keep last cron run time in db. And simple code would do the job:

```
if (last_run_time + delay < current_time) {
  run_your_cron()
}
```

This approach is used by wordpress, you can find more about it on internet. The main problem is that, if there are no users, your cron will not run. But if there are no users, is your code useful?

Otherwise you have to develop some kind of API, and trigger from the outside, e.g. server where you have access to crontab.